# Pylons Controller Tests Don't Pass Request Params

Tags: unit-testing, pylons, functional-testing

We're trying to setup controller tests for our Pylons app. I made a very simple controller and a very simple test. The tests looks like:

```
class TestMainController(TestController):
    def test_index(self):
        response = self.app.get(url(controller='main', action='index', var1 = '1'), params={'var2':'2'})
        print response.req
        assert False
```

Meanwhile, the controller looks something like this:

```
class MainController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        print request
        print request.params
```

For some reason, when we run this code, we get the following output:

```
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
GET /_test_vars HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:80
<Request at 0x36d6950 GET http://localhost/_test_vars>
UnicodeMultiDict([])
GET /main/index/?var1=1&var2=2 HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:80

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

The TestApp thinks its sending the proper request, but the request that hits the controller is wrong. Anyone have any idea what's going on here? We're dead in the water on tests at the moment.

Comment: This code works just fine for me in a freshly-created Pylons 1.0 project.  It must be something you're doing elsewhere in your code.  How do you import 'request' in your main controller?  Do do you do any special setup (e.g. request._push_object) somewhere in your test setUp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Marius's comment, it turns out we were doing an earlier requset to setup a our app. That request was screwing with things.